# NumberOfPages returns only 1 page and not the 16 pages of the PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I need to read the values in a PDF file which has 16 pages.  I did not create the PDF file.  The form starts on page 3, the two first pages are just text.

The version of my iTextSharp DLL is : 5.5.10.0

When I run this line of code (vb.net) :

```
Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
```

The pdfReader.NumberOfPages returns 1.

So I cannot read the value of the form.  Anyone has an idea why I get that?

I tested my code with other PDF files and its working.  I can read all pages and fields.  This is complete code snippet that I use for my test.  It just open the PDF and loops through the fields.

```
Try
    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "D:\myFile.pdf"
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)

    Dim pdfFields As AcroFields = pdfReader.AcroFields
    Dim pdfVal As String = ""

    For Each pdfField As KeyValuePair(Of String, AcroFields.Item) In pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
        pdfVal = pdfFields.GetField(pdfField.Key)
        ShowMessage("KEY=[" & pdfField.Key & "]...VALUE=[" & pdfVal & "]", mINFO)
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    ShowMessage(ex.ToString, mERROR)
End Try
```

What could explain that iText only reads page 1 and not the 15 other pages of the PDF file?

One thing I noticed it the PDF file I am able to parse correctly are version 6.  While the PDF I have problems with are version 7.  Could this be the reason?

Is it possible for me with iTextSharp to save the PDF to a lower version and then retry to read it?

Thank you for helping.

## EDITED - SOLUTION FOUND

As KenS suggested, my PDF was an XFA form.  This is my code to get the form in an XML Document object

```
Try

    Dim pdfTemplate As String = "D:\myFile.pdf"
    Dim pdfReader As New PdfReader(pdfTemplate)
    Dim pdfFields As AcroFields = pdfReader.AcroFields

    If pdfFields.Xfa.XfaPresent = True Then

        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(pdfFields.Xfa.DatasetsNode.OuterXml)

        //Your code here to parse through xmlDoc

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The file is not valid.")
    End If

    pdfReader.Close()
    pdfReader.Dispose()

Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Most likely the additional pages are not PDF, but an XFA form. In which case the actual PDF portion will be simply a page which says 'you need the latest version of Acrobat Reader' or something similar. PDF readers can't, in general, read XFA forms because they are written in XML, not PDF. Of course, without seeing the actual PDF file, its not possible to be certain.

Comment: Thank you.  You put me on the right track.  I searched Google for a bit of help on XFA and found the necessary code to open the file and parse it as an XML.  Now I can retreive the values.

Comment: If you have fixed the issue it would be good of you to post an answer for anyone who may have the same issue in the future :)